Amplify Gen2 + React: How to query a DB sorted by a key with pagination?
I have this data model:
const schema = a.schema({
  Messages: a
    .model({
      Timestamp: a.string().required(),
      From: a.string().required(),
      To: a.string().required(),
      Body: a.string().required(),
    ])
});

I want to query it and display the latest 10 messages, and paginate to display older messages.
How can I achieve that?
I tried adding:
    .model({
...
      Dummy: a.integer().default(0),
    }).secondaryIndexes(index => [
      index('Dummy').sortKeys(['Timestamp']).queryField('listByTimestamp')
    ])

But then listByTimestamp() doesn't have a limit argument as in simple list().
